# Wildfly how to remove module such as Mail

Tags: jboss, module, wildfly

For the purpose of slimming services, I have attempted to remove the mail module under the javax.

When removing all references to this module in the standalone-full.xml and attempting to run Wildfly, I receive the following **exception**:

> 13:09:36,301 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread)
>   JBAS014601: Error booting the container:
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadError: javax.mail.api:main    at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException.toError(ModuleLoadException.java:78)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.Module.getPathsUnchecked(Module.java:1392)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:563)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]   at
>   org.wildfly.extension.batch.BatchSubsystemDefinition.(BatchSubsystemDefinition.java:86)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.batch.BatchSubsystemParser.readElement(BatchSubsystemParser.java:59)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.batch.BatchSubsystemParser.readElement(BatchSubsystemParser.java:47)
>     at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
>   [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69)
>   [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:1131)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_4(StandaloneXml.java:458)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:145)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:107)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110)
>   [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
>   [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:104)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:331)
>   [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:259)
>   [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
>
> 13:09:36,321 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015950:
>   WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" stopped in 20ms Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was
>   removed in 8.0

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Is there another place I need to remove a module dependency?  If so, where in which file is it located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing up modules and subsystems.

To reduce the number of runtime services, you may remove an extension and the corresponding subsystem definition from `standalone.xml`.

If you remove a module from the installation, you must remove all its dependents or make sure they are not used at runtime.

This will not work in your example since `javaee.api` depends on `javax.mail.api`, and `org.wildfly.extension.batch` (and most other modules) depend on `javaee.api`.